# Yii1.1 create a model with DB View that join 2 tables together

Tags: php, yii, model

I am new to Yii1.1 framework and i would like to ask:
How to create a model with DB View that join 2 tables together 
or is there other alternatives??

If DEMO is provided , then it will be a great great help.

Thank you for you all .

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please read  [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) article for better asking. You should not ask users to provide complete solution for you.

Comment: I just want a simply DEMO not the solution and i am not forcing them to provide the solution to me but is a great help if provided.

Thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please go through the below link,

http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/285/accessing-data-in-a-join-table-with-the-related-models/